# How to iterate through a dictionary and calculate the values based on the values from a list?

Tags: python

There are 8 motors and I am monitoring their speeds. I have a dictionary through which I am iterating and then I am calculating the difference in the speed with the individual retrieved speeds.

- Then I have to compare if the change is less than the maximum values for each motor (which is there in the speeds list for each motor).
- Currently what is happening is it is calculating the difference only for the last speed
- Retrieved speeds dictionary looks like {1: 8490, 2: 7920, 3: 8460, 4: 7890, 5: 8460, 6: 7950, 7: 8430, 8: 6720}

```
speeds = {1: 8800, 2: 8800, 3: 8800, 4: 8800, 5: 8800, 6: 8800, 7: 8800, 8: 7300}
for index , speed in speeds.items():
    print("Please print these for me to understand", speed, retrieved_speeds_dict[index])
    absolute_change = abs(speed - retrieved_speeds_dict[index] )

rpms = [500, 600, 500, 700, 800, 100, 200, 500]
for each_rpm in rpms:
    if absolute_change > each_rpm:
        err_msg = err_msg + f"Out of range by {absolute_change}"
        print(err_msg)
    else:
        self.log.info(f"Speed is correct with {absolute_change}")
```

Can someone please help to fix the loops so that it calculates the difference and compare it with each rpm value.

Comment: I don't see where you define "retrieved_speeds_dict"

Comment: @RIPPLR it's this. `{1: 8490, 2: 7920, 3: 8460, 4: 7890, 5: 8460, 6: 7950, 7: 8430, 8: 6720}`

Comment: You have two loops.  You set `absolute_change` on each iteration of the first loop.  When the first loop exits, `absolute_change` has the value from the last iteration.  You then use it in the second loop, without changing it, so it retains that last value for all of the second loop.  It sounds like you need to either combine the two loops, or else save each `absolute_change` value in the first loop (rather than just the last value).

Comment: So, are you saying that `speeds` is the target speed, `retrieved_speeds` is the measured speed, and `rpms` is the acceptable tolerance?

Comment: @TimRoberts, yes that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the kind of thing you want?

```
retrieved_speeds = { 1: 8490, 2: 7920, 3: 8460, 4: 7890, 5: 8460, 6: 7950, 7: 8430, 8: 6720 }
speeds = {1: 8800, 2: 8800, 3: 8800, 4: 8800, 5: 8800, 6: 8800, 7: 8800, 8: 7300}
rpms = [500, 600, 500, 700, 800, 100, 200, 500]

for  desired,actual,tolerance in zip( speeds.items(), retrieved_speeds.values(), rpms):
    index, desired = desired
    variance = abs(actual-desired)
    if variance > tolerance:
        delta = abs(variance-tolerance)
        err_msg = f"{index} Out of range by {delta}"
        print(err_msg)
    else:
        print(f"{index} Speed is correct within {variance}")
```

Output:

```
1 Speed is correct within 310
2 Out of range by 280
3 Speed is correct within 340
4 Out of range by 210
5 Speed is correct within 340
6 Out of range by 750
7 Out of range by 170
8 Out of range by 80
```

Answer (score 0):

```
retrieved_speeds_dict = {1: 8490, 2: 7920, 3: 8460, 4: 7890, 5: 8460, 6: 7950, 
7: 8430, 8: 6720}
speeds = {1: 8800, 2: 8800, 3: 8800, 4: 8800, 5: 8800, 6: 8800, 7: 8800, 8: 
7300}
for a, each_rpm in zip(speeds.items(), rpms):
    index, speed = a
    print("Please print these for me to understand", speed, 
    retrieved_speeds_dict[index])
    absolute_change = abs(speed - retrieved_speeds_dict[index] )
    if absolute_change > each_rpm:
        err_msg = f"Out of range by {absolute_change}"
        print(err_msg)
    else:
        print(f"Speed is correct with {absolute_change}")
```

Using the zip function, you can loop through the dictionary and list at the same time